# cornerSubPix in OpenCV: purpose and application

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I tried to understand the `cornerSubPix` API in OpenCV for its idea behind and usefulness. I read the explanation in the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornersubpix) and can't understand how it works and how it is useful.
Can somebody explain me how it works and how it is useful at corner refinement? I checked my corner detection application for without `cornerSubPix` and with `cornerSubPix`. Not much difference in output image, but it takes time to process.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can´t explain better how it works than the actual documentation but I can help you with the: "how it is useful at corner refinement" Part.

The corners you find are in Pixel Coordinates. This means a Pixel can be at Position (10,10) or (11,11) but not at Position (11.3,11.2)

Subpixel refinement allows edges at such positions and helps to find a better position.

Comment: Yes you are right. I found the discussion in the Jean-Yves Bouguet's paper " Pyramidal Implementation of the Lucus Kanade Feature Tracker Description of the algorithm" (section 2.5).